# Getting response as null in http post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following code:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Update(int studentId = 0, int subjectId = 0)
        {
            Engine engine = new Engine(studentId, subjectId);
            List<Chapter> chapterList = engine.GetChapters();

            return View(chapterList);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(List<Chapter> model)      
        {           

            return View(model);
        }
```

**Update.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Chapter>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update";
}
<h2>
    Update</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "StudyPlan", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(chapterItem => item.included)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </fieldset>


}
```

I want when a user selects checkboxes, the response should come in `httppost` method of controller. But I am getting null value Update method. Am I doing something wrong

Comment: how does your `chapter` model look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `for` instead of `foreach`. In that case checkbox will be rendered as

```
<input type='checkbox' name='Model[0].included'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='Model[1].included'/>
...
```

and then ModelBinder will successfully create model

Example:

```
@model List<Chapter>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update";
}
<h2>
    Update</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "StudyPlan", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <table>
            @for (int i =0;i<Model.Count;i++)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Model[i].name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(chapterItem => Model[i].included)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </fieldset>


}
```

PS. in that example Model changed to `List<>` from `IEnumerable`

It happens because MVC analyze expression in CheckBoxFor method. And it this expression is array accessor, then it generates different control name. And based on Name ModelBinder successfully creates `List<>`

Comment: Now, the property `name` and `id` is coming as null, how to fix that?

Comment: They are coming as null, as you haven't any Input elements with them. If you want to receive them in model, you need to add them. You can add them as `Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].id)` and `Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].name)`. MVC create model object based on input\textarea fields on the page.

Answer (score 0):

As Sergey suggested, use a for loop, but try this:

```
@for (int i =0;i<Model.Count;i++)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].id)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].included)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```